# subprocess.Popen hangs when starting adb server

Tags: android, python

### test.py:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE,STDOUT

os.system("adb kill-server")
p = Popen("adb devices", stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
for str in p.communicate()[0].split("\r\n"):
    print str
p.wait()
p.terminate()
```

**This script can exit normally when executing standalone.**

---

### test2.py

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
p = Popen("python test.py", stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
for str in p.communicate()[0].split("\r\n"):
    print str
p.wait()
p.terminate()
```

**This script calls "test.py", and will hang at "p.communicate()".
How does this happen?**

Answer (score 0):

Add `shell=True` in `test.py` as shown below and then execute `test2.py`.

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE,STDOUT

os.system("adb kill-server")
p = Popen("adb devices", stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
for str in p.communicate()[0].split("\r\n"):
    print str
p.wait()
p.terminate()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution on my local, but it doesn't work, still hanging there.